# Epicor API Documentation

Tags: c#, vb.net, openedge, epicorerp

Just wondering if anyone knows of any sort of comprehensive documentation for the C#/VB API for Epicor 9.  Also, a reference the ABL (Progress OpenEdge) language would be helpful as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

Here is the latest (currently 11.3) set of documentation for Progress OpenEdge and the ABL language: [PSDN](https://community.progress.com/technicalusers/w/openedgegeneral/1107.openedge-11-3-product-documentation.aspx)

Look at ABL essentials and ABL reference.

Comment: Thanks!  I have version 10.2a but I was able to find the documentation for that version from the link you provided.

Comment: Do you know of any good tutorial how to create a procedure in ABL and where to store it in epicor?  I see the documentation but not sure where it is stored or how it is loaded to get called.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the Epicor 9 API I personally do not know of any (good) documentation. In my opinion, the soap api was never really "designed" its just the Epicor internal functions straight off. The best way to figure out how to use the different Epicor API functions I've found so far (which is also working rather well):

1. Checkout the definition files available in your public www folder (or install them now) by just loading the API urls in your browser.
2. Run a full trace from within Epicor 9 for the workflow or function you are trying to do via the API.
3. Study the Epicor tracelog and do exactly the same api calls (in the same order) via the Epicor SOAP API.

Its a tedious process but once you started stacking the API calls from Epicor together into your own easier to use functions it starts getting rather painless.

p.s. Please also check the ICE documentation for the business objects as such.

Best
Mikael

Comment: What database does Epicor use, is it possible to access the database directly and make changes

Comment: Epicor has an MS SQL Server backend, however, I strongly recommend against bypassing Epicor's business logic and accessing the database directly.

Comment: Not MS SQL. Progress is where the heart of Epicor 9 lies, however some installations do use MS SQL for the datastore. FWIW, I agree with the tracelog route mentioned in the answer, you soon get used to it.

Comment: Epicor 10 uses MS SQL.

Comment: Can it be used in Java?